# Make Fiori header fields invisible

Tags: javascript, sap-fiori, sapui5

I want to hide the Fiori app header field (which is used in several apps) in one of the apps, but SAP has not provided any extension to hide these type of fields.

How can I make Fiori header fields invisible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Adoption (RTA) of UI5 could be used to remove/hide/rename/etc. UI elements. If you start the application with a user who is a key user (has SAP_UI_FLEX_KEY_USER) then you can switch to adoption mode via the 'Adapt UI' button & do the adjustments via hovering over individual UI elements. The result can be published and transported from dev landscape.

More at: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw751abap/7.51.0/en-US/5c/424437bf794f809087fdce391149f2/content.htm?no_cache=true

Comment: Hi, Unfortunatley, RTA is not enabled to those apps/ WebIde as we are using SAP CLOUD provided services(Gateway with SAP), I want to achieve this dynamically using Javascript code!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

create a new library which contains a control which extends the PersinfoControl of library hcm.lib.common. In this extention overwrite the init function of this control, first call super, then replace the header with a custom fragment(copy of the original without the button).
Extend the Family Data app an replace the main View. Replace the reference to library hcm.lib.common with your newly created library.